# Mobile optimized container for an advocacy email

Tags: html, css

I work at a political nonprofit. I've been trying to develop a template for advocacy emails with a container on the right side for quick actions. The container looks fine on desktop and iOS but it looks super messed up on droid (the container overlaps the text on the left side). I'm trying to figure out how to mobile optimize the container but can't quite figure it out. I'm also not even sure if this is the best way to do something like this? Here's the code:

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 500px; background-color: #f89c27; 
text-align: center;" class="container">
<h2 align="center">headline</h2>
<p align="center">text</p>
<a href="website/"><button>Click here to sign</button></a></div>


<style type="text/css">
img {
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; max-width: 100%;
}
body {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-
serif; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-size: 14px; height: 
100% !important; line-height: 1.6em; margin: 0; padding: 0; -ms-text-
size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; width: 100% 
!important;
}
.ExternalClass {
width: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass {
line-height: 100%;
}
div {
float: right;
margin: 2em;
padding: 1em;
}
body {
margin: 0em;
padding: 0em;
}
button {
font-size: 20px;
padding: 8px 20px;
background-color: #A9A9A9; 
}
```